Telegram Bot on aiogram3 with PyDrive
Bot uses the PyDrive library, where autoauthentication takes place. Everything works normally, but only 2-3 hours, then it stops working. Can’t figure out what the error is? There’s a suggestion that it’s because you need to re-autovalidate
I don’t know, I read the documentation, tried to look it up on Google Platform, but nothing helped

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
